# rails_admin can't delete HABTM object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many, rails-admin

My two models are

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :releases
end

class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
end

class ReleasesTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When I try to delete a team or release on rails_admin, I get an error:

```
undefined method `releases_teams' for #<Release:0x007fe57b0a9f20>
```

raised on this line

```
def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  if respond_to_without_attributes?(method, true)
    super
  else
    match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
    match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super #ERROR RAISED HERE
  end
end
```

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**

After Pavan's comment, I removed ReleasesTeam model. DB schema looks like this now:

```
create_table "releases", force: true do |t|
  t.text     "notes"
end

create_table "teams", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
end

create_table "releases_teams", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.integer "team_id"
  t.integer "release_id"
end
```

I reset the DB and still getting the same error

Comment: Seems like you created a `model` for your `join table`.If so,you should delete that model,because `HABTM join table` should not have a `model` associated with it.

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Rails to 4.1.4.

**Issue**

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1984

**thebenedict commented**

This is a rails issue, not rails_admin. HABTM implementation changed in rails 4 in a way that breaks reflection on association names. There's a fix in 4-1-stable, and upgrading rails to 4.1.4 fixes this for me. Also see [rails/rails#14682](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/14682)